# Download CFM page as Word Doc

Tags: coldfusion, document

I'm trying to render the output of a .cfm into a Word doc using `cfinclude` like so:

```
<cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment; filename=""MyDocument.doc""" />
<cfcontent type="application/msword" reset="true">
<cfinclude template="PageToDownload.cfm">
```

Since `cfinclude` outputs the .cfm as html, this should theoretically work.  However, doing this downloads a document that errors in Word with "A text/xml declaration may occur only at the very beginning of input."  I inspected the downloaded document with Notepad++ and saw this at the top:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/tr/xhtml1/dtd/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
...
```

If I remove the empty line, the ?xml, and the !DOCTYPE (basically cut off everything up to `<html`), this document opens in Word.  Is it possible to strip off the xml and DOCTYPE tags and start at `<html` using `cfinclude`?  Or, is there another approach I should take?

Comment: I would do `.docx` since it is a zip of XML, but event would be time consuming. Saving an HTML and trying to make it pretend to be a `.doc` seems to be asking for trouble.

Comment: Why not just remove the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` from "PageToDownload.cfm" if it's not needed, since that script appears to be what's adding it to the output?

Comment: @SOS This is a simplified version of the program I'm working on.  "PageToDownload" in my case is used in other functions that need that xml tag, so that's not an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your technique, what you can do is put the contents of `PageToDownload.cfm` into a variable using `<cfsavecontent>`.  Once the contents are in said variable, you could strip out everything prior to the opening `<html>` tag and then `<cfoutput>` that variable after your `<cfheader>` and `<cfcontent>` statements.

Your code could look something like this.

```
<!--- Save contents of file to download into fileContents variable --->
<cfsavecontent variable="fileContent">
    <cfinclude template="PageToDownload.cfm">
</cfsavecontent>

<!--- Strip out contents prior to the opening <html> tag --->
<cfset pos = findNoCase("<html", fileContent)>
<cfset fileContent = mid(fileContent, pos, 1000000)>

<!--- Output fileContent after the header statements --->
<cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment; filename=""MyDocument.doc""" />
<cfcontent type="application/msword" reset="true">
<cfoutput>#fileContent#</cfoutput>
```